# Index deletion on a particular table

Tags: db2

How to drop index on a particular table. According to the syntax as

```
DROP INDEX <INDEX_NAME>
```

It will delete the index on that particular schema.
My requirement is I want to create an index named I9 on all the table under a particular schema. For example these are the list of tables under schema s1 (t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6).I have created I9 index on all the tables.
Now I want to delete the index only on table t3.

Can some one please let me know the syntax for this.

Comment: You can't create multiple indexes with the same name in DB2. And because the index name is unique, `drop index` will only drop a single index as well.

Comment: Thanks & sorry for the basic question , as i am new to this